# Why does inotify error when watching one directory but not another?

Tags: linux, kernel

A program that uses inotify with IN_CREATE to watch a directory for file creation fails on some directories but works on others.  For example it works on /home/randomtroll/testdir but fails on /home/randomtroll ; both have the same owners and permissions.  When it fails, the read returns EINVAL.  The inotify descriptor and watch have been successfully created; the buffer into which it reads is aligned properly and large enough to accommodate the data read.

Comment: what **are** the permissions? Can you actually add your code?

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible test case. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The buffer into which I read the inotify descriptor was too small.  I made it large enough to accommodate the names of files I was looking for; the creation of files with names longer than that caused a read error.  One cannot limit how many bytes  one reads when one reads an inotify descriptor.  This seems like a bug to me.